# Add element to a list dynamically instead of invoking the list name directly

Tags: r, list, dynamic, element

I have created a list using this code:

```
i=1
assign(paste0("dat",i,"_list"),list()) #creates empty list called dat1_list
```

and I would like to add a dataframe to that list, which I can do like this:

```
dat1_list[[1]]<-iris
```

HOWEVER I don't want to call the list directly by hard coding its actual name (as in the line immediately above) but instead I need to use the constituents of its name ("dat", current value of i, "_list") dynamically.

I have tried using paste0() like I did to create the list (second line of code, above), but I can't make it work.

Thank you for your time, attention and advice! Mark

Comment: Anytime you are trying to embed a index in a variable name, that's usually a sign that you are doing things in a very non-R-like way. It's way better to use (possibly named) lists. Using `get/assign` is very much an anti-pattern for most cases in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this but I think it's a terrible idea - this code is hard to write and hard to read.

```
i=1
obj_name = paste0("dat",i,"_list")

## initialize the empty list
assign(obj_name,list())

## verify
dat1_list
# list()

## assign a value to the 1st item of the list
assign(obj_name, `[[<-`(get(obj_name), i = 1, value = iris[1:3, ]))

## verify
dat1_list
# [[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

## extend
assign(obj_name, `[[<-`(get(obj_name), i = 2, value = 3:5))

## verify
# [[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 4 5
```

Perhaps you'd be better using a list of lists?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Gregor. Would you mind checking the syntax of your suggested code? It doesn't seem to work and you are correct that it's difficult to read so I'm having trouble understanding how to debug it. I will also look into your suggestion of using a list of lists. Thank you!

Comment: Thought I had it working, but apparently I was missing  a needed `assign()`. Editing now...

Comment: Great, thank you! And I got it working as a "list of lists" so thank you for that suggestion!